# Remove Item From List in Foreach

Tags: c#, list, removeall

I want to remove an item from list, I searched, I tried all versions of Remove(Remove, RemoveAt, RemoveAll) methods, but I couldn't figure it out. The item is always there. My Code :

```
foreach (Question q in questions)
{
    foreach (QuestionValue qv in q.QuestionValueList)
    {
        if (m_User.OrganizationRole.QuestionValuePermissionList.Where(p => p.QuestionValue.QuestionValue_Id == qv.QuestionValue_Id).Count() == 0)
        {
            int i = questions.FindIndex(p => p.Question_Id == q.Question_Id);
            QuestionValue item = questions[i].QuestionValueList.Find(p => p.QuestionValue_Id == qv.QuestionValue_Id);

            questions[i].QuestionValueList.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always include full error messages. Which when read, should answer your question.

Comment: Actually there is no error, it runs without an error, but it doesn't remove the item.

Comment: The code doesn’t make sense. You already have the `Question` object so why look for it again? Also note you can’t iterate a collection and modify it at the same time. That will cause an issue. But first, have you run the code in a debugger line by line and see what it does exactly?

Comment: foreach (Question q in questions)
        {
            foreach (QuestionValue qv in q.QuestionValueList)
            {
                if (m_User.OrganizationRole.QuestionValuePermissionList.Where(p => p.QuestionValue.QuestionValue_Id == qv.QuestionValue_Id).Count() == 0)
                {
                    q.QuestionValueList.Remove(qv);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

Comment: Do you think anyone wants to read that? If you have something new, _edit_ the question.